# Making an Ajax call to a module controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, module, hmvc

I have a module that is running an ajax request through jquery, and I'm trying to send the ajax request to a controller within the same module folder.

Here is my code:

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "../modules/test/controllers/test_controller/get_data",
        success: function(json) {
            alert(json.test);
        },
        error: function() {
            // Errored
        }
    });
```

In firebug, the url seems correct, but I get a 404 page error being thrown in the html output of the request console. How can I access the controller within the modules folder? Do I need to change anything in the third_party/MX/ files? (the files required to use modules)

Comment: which framework are you using?

Comment: it seems to me  like you are providing path based on the directory structure. Have you tried /test/test_controller/get_data ?? And is the controller or method that you are trying to hit accessible if you paste the url in the browser window?

Comment: @UmairKhan No, I get a 404 page error when trying to access it in the browser window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url: "../modules/test/controllers/test_controller/get_data",
```

Write in this path `base_url();` or `site_url();`

For example

```
<script>
var base_url = <?=base_url();?>
</script>
```

in your js file:

```
url: base_url + 'controller/method'
```

Comment: I've actually got a base_url variable set up in js but that doesn't help either. The path I've got in there at the moment says it's the same in firebug.

Comment: maybe check csrf filter enabled in config and check your routes. http://aymsystems.com/ajax-csrf-protection-codeigniter-20/

Comment: Okay, so it is set to false at the moment. Should I set it to true? And what should I be looking for in the routes file?

Comment: ok. Set it to false. If you use hmvc and have module read this https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home
maybe system cannot find in controller method were init module and so return 404 error, and also check chmod to files and folder

Comment: Okay, I set it to false. the chmod of the folders are each 777 (for the modules folder and it's subfolders), but what exactly were you trying to point me to in that link?

Comment: Oh I found it! "All module controllers are accessible from the URL via module/controller/method or simply module/method if the module and controller names match." Perfect! Also just noticed that this is exactly what you mentioned in your answer, I just didn't understand why you did it. Sir, you're a gentleman and a scholar!